# Tableau - Common Table Expression (CTE) SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, tableau-api, common-table-expression

I am connecting Tableau with SQL Server and I am trying to use the T-SQL query.
I just want to know, does Tableau support CTE (Common Table Expression)?

I came across this article and it said CTE is possible: http://kb.tableau.com/articles/howto/using-common-table-expressions

Here's my query:

```
WITH Test (Store) AS 
(
    SELECT 
        Store
    FROM
        FiscalReporting.dbo.LBR_STR_ORG
)
SELECT
    Store
FROM
    Test
```

When I am running this query, I get an error message. Please let me know if I am doing something wrong.

Most of my SQL queries are built with CTE. So it would be greatly appreciated if I get any help. Also, I am new to Tableau.

Thanks!

Comment: remove (store) and check "WITH Test (Store) AS" to "WITH Test AS"

Comment: ***WHAT*** error are you getting? Remember: we **cannot** read your screen, nor your mind - you'll **have to show us!**

Comment: I removed (store) it doesn't work. This is the error message I am getting;                                                                                   [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WITH'.
[Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.
[Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Comment: Sorry, Tableau doesn't support using CTE's in custom SQL. Someone posted a work-around which was basically creating a table on the server, then using a select statement to access the data. I ended up creating a view (you can use CTE's in your create view statement), but it would be better if Tableau simply supported any valid query. [Link to reason tableau errors out on CTE usage](https://community.tableau.com/ideas/3168)

Comment: But this is the recent answer I got from Tableau, it says it support  CTE, http://kb.tableau.com/articles/howto/using-common-table-expressions. Maybe I am doing something wrong

Comment: I'm not on Tableau 10 yet, so maybe they've updated it.  I was unable to see the " Initial SQL" from my screen -- maybe not available in vs. 9 or perhaps the way IT has it set up.  Sorry I couldn't be of more help.

Comment: Read the document. It doesn't say they support CTEs with custom SQL. They show you can select into a temp table with initial SQL, and then select from that temp table with your custom SQL. Assuming you need custom SQL in the first place

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16777794)

Answer (score 2):

Tableau does not support CTE expressions in "Custom SQL". But it does in "Initial SQL".

Here are two examples, how to use it:

https://kb.tableau.com/articles/howto/using-common-table-expressions

https://dabblingwithdata.wordpress.com/2016/12/10/actually-you-can-use-variables-ctes-and-other-fancy-sql-with-tableau-after-all/

The solution involves using "Initial SQL" where you can create temp table (the one with # at the beggining - SQL Server) and then you refer to this temp table in your "Custom SQL"