# Initial SQL for CTE query in Tableau

Tags: mysql, sql, count, tableau-api, common-table-expression

I am trying to run the following SQL Query

```
WITH Tap AS (SELECT DISTINCT 
    account_id,
    MONTH(t_start) AS month,
    DAY(t_start) AS day
FROM knowledge_repeat)
SELECT DISTINCT 
    account_id, 
    COUNT(account_id) as 'Unique',
    CASE
        WHEN COUNT(account_id) > 10 THEN 'Super Loyal'
        WHEN COUNT(account_id) > 5 AND COUNT(account_id) < 10 THEN 'Semi Loyal'
        WHEN COUNT(account_id) > 2 AND COUNT(account_id) < 5 THEN 'Tried It'
        WHEN COUNT(account_id) = 1 THEN 'Tried it once'
        ELSE 'Crazy Keen'
    END AS 'Loyalty Rating'
FROM Tap
GROUP BY account_id
```

But get the following error

> [MySQL][ODBC 8.0(w) Driver][mysqld-5.7.25-google-log]You have an error
>   in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL
>   server version for the right syntax to use near 'Tap AS (SELECT
>   DISTINCT account_id, MONTH(t_start) AS month, DAY(t_start) AS' at line
>   1 Initial SQL Error. Check that the syntax is correct and that you
>   have access privileges to the requested database.

I can't undertand why - it works fine in SSMS and on various forums I've read CTE queries should work in the Initial SQL part of Tableau.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tableau - Common Table Expression (CTE) SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42570138/tableau-common-table-expression-cte-sql-server)

Comment: Please clarify how you're running that cte in Tableau and at what point you're getting the error, if the link above doesn't answer your question.  Also, what version of Tableau?

Comment: Your error showing "mysqld-5.7.25-google-log" ... This code will only work on MySQL 8 , not on lower version

Comment: You're doing things the hard way. Try just pointing Tableau at the original table, knowledge_repeat, not using custom SQL. If you learn more about how Tableau works, you can let it generate optimized SQL for you based on the view you want. You'll accomplish more, quicker and with more flexibility. Custom SQL is rarely needed. Otherwise, you're giving up one of the main benefits that Tableau brings and only using it as a drawing tool. There is a learning curve and it's hard at first to trust it to generate the SQL, but your SQL concepts knowledge still pays off. Well worth the time to learn.

Comment: @AlexBlakemore are you suggesting I should be able to just do this via calculated fields within Tableau if I just keep it pointed at the original table?

Comment: @adampitt3 Exactly. You can use calculated fields, as well as groups, sets and other Tableau features during your analysis. Then as you work with Tableau, adding or removing fields, filters etc to try different views, Tableau will generate optimized SQL for the view of the moment based on the data source (tables) that you are referencing. As you learn to use Tableau better, you’ll find it faster and more flexible way to work. Think of SQL like machine language that is generated by SQL. You can work directly at the SQL level when needed, but that really is rarely necessary.

Comment: By the way, when you use a field as a *dimension* in Tableau, that is analogous to using that field in a GROUP BY clause in SQL.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL 5.7, which you are running as it can be seen in the error message, does not support `WITH` clauses (aka common table expressions). This feature was added in version 8.0 only.

For your query, you *could* simply turn the CTE to a subquery. But I still suspect that your code can be largely simplified (assuming, of course, that it currently produces the results that you want on some non-MySQL datatabase).

Here is a shot at it:

```
select 
    account_id,
    cnt `Unique`,
    case
        when cnt > 10 then `Super Loyal`
        when cnt > 5  then `Semi Loyal`
        when cnt > 2  then `Tried It`
        when cnt = 1  then `Tried it once`
        else `Crazy Keen`
    end as `Loyalty Rating`
from (
    select
        account_id,
        count(distinct month(t_start), month(t_day)) as cnt
    from knowledge_repeat
    group by account_id
) t
```

Rationale:

- this counts distinct month/day tuples per `account_id` (which seems to be the purpose of your nested `select`s), relying on a MySQL extension to the SQL standard which allows tuples in `count(distinct)` - we could also phrase this as `count(distinct date_format(t_start, '%m-%d')) as cnt`
- I used a subquery just ouf of laziness to type the same aggregate function again and again in the `case` expression, but it is not strictly needed here
- the `case` expression executes sequentially - so there is no need to specify upper bounds for the conditions, since they are covered by the previous branches
- you need to use backtickts to quote identifiers rather than single quotes